# How do you get git to ignore all contents of a directory?

Tags: git

I have a git directory which contains the a whole bunch of files and then has a directory called 'sessions'. 'sessions' contains cookie information for my web.py program.

I need the folder 'sessions' to remain in the git repository because without the folder the program does not function correctly. I don't need the actual contents of folder being stored in the git directory.

So the question is:

How can I get git to ignore the contents of a folder but not the folder itself?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If I'm remembering correctly, you can do this by creating a `.gitignore` file in the `sessions` folder with `[^.]*` as its contents.

Comment: I tried this as a test, but it didn't work. I must've done something wrong.

Comment: `*` worked for me - what is `[^.]*` doing that `*` is potentially not?

Comment: The [^.]* says: don't ignore files whose names begin with ".", like .gitignore.  Also: you might think this didn';t do anything - I did - because this won't take effect until you commit .gitignore.

Comment: Strictly, this answer is incorrect: it shows a way to make Git track a directory but ignore everything *except any and all dotfiles*, while the question is about keeping the directory and ignoring *everything* in it. Since technically it isn't possible for Git to track a completely empty directory, a compromise is to have Git track a *single* file (and *only* that file): `.gitignore`,in it. Which is exactly what Mathias V's answer below does.

Answer (score 58):

Add a sessions/.gitignore file with

```
*
!.gitignore
```

The second line tells git not to ignore the .gitignore file, so the folder is not empty but everything else is ignored.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering old questions – it helps future Googlers like me. An existing project of mine uses this answer with success. Also, this answer explains the syntax it uses, unlike the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since [July 2007](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=427078), [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) does describe the exclusion patterns.

> **If the pattern ends with a slash**, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but **it would only find a match with a directory**.
>
> **In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo** (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git).

As [illustrated by this thread](http://markmail.org/message/k3axwb4sy7dhrz67#query:gitignore%20patterns+page:1+mid:4mcq2kt6o6smdiv7+state:results), that pattern was not always expressed with a '/' for matching directory.